# Regex JavaScript capture till (before) optional string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a regex

```
(\/)?([\s\S]+)(?:@bigletterbot)?
```

When I match : `/random@bigletterbot`

Expected Output:

`["/random@bigletterbot","/","random"]`

However it is giving

`["/random@bigletterbot","/","random@bigletterbot"]`

Moreover when I match

`Hello
World!`

it is giving desired output. I tested at [regex101.](https://www.regex101.com/#javascript)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Requirements:

`/` is optional and if present should be captured,
`[\s\S]+` is meant to be captured:
which can be:
`Hello
World`

 or
`Hello @ World`*I thinks **@** is making it difficult otherwise*`[^@]+`*should work*
 and third part is a **optional** string `@bigletterbot` which should **not be captured**

Comment: Making the `@bigletterbot` optional does not mean it will be omitted in the match. Do you mean to use [`(\/)?([\s\S]+)(?=@bigletterbot)`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4mK5/1)? What are the exact requirements?

Comment: No I do not want to capture @bigletterbot which may or may not be inputed by the user due to [second point in this](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode)

Comment: Then try just matching any 1+ character but `@` with `[^@]+`: [`(\/)?([^@]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4mK5/2)

Comment: Another way is to use a tempered greedy token: [`(\/)?((?:(?!@bigletterbot)[\s\S])+)`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4mK5/3). Or based on your latest update - [`(\/)?([^@]*(?:@\B[^@]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4mK5/4)

Comment: Thank You! so much it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you may use to match and capture an optional `/` followed with any characters but a `@` or `@` symbols that are not followed with a word character is

```
(\/)?([^@]*(?:@\B[^@]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ4mK5/4)

The part I add is `[^@]*(?:@\B[^@]*)*`:

- `[^@]*` - 0+ characters other than `@`
- `(?:@\B[^@]*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `@\B` - `@` that is not followed with a word character (as `\B` is a non-word boundary)
  - `[^@]*` - 0+ characters other than `@`

When a substring is not to be "matched" (you say `@something` should not be *captured*, but actually mean it should not be matched), it means you need to match up to that substring. Thus, a negated character class solution is the best here, but it  is complicated a little because you want to allow `@` + non-word characters combinations. The `\B` should cope with those situations as user names should conform to the `@\w+` pattern (so, all the @mentions will be safely stopped from matching with `@\B`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think I should stop wasting time and delete my facebook account and start spending more and more time here, I'm loving stackoverflow...

Comment: Ok then fb account remains will use it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, try following regex:

```
/((\/?)([^@]+).*)/g
```

Based on your sample input, output will be:

```
1.  `/random@bigletterbot`
2.  `/`
3.  `random`
```

Try [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xE9pD5/2)

Comment: The problem is user could input `random
@ words` in my [Telegram bot](http://telegram.me/bigletterbot) in which `@ words` will not be captured

Comment: hmm, so what is expected behavior? What should be captured in this particular case?

Comment: Are you saying, random @ words shouldn't be captured? But if you want, it to capture with spaces, my regex is already doing that